# import xsd with no namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

As in the title, how do you import schema that has no targetNamespace defined?

I've got following case:

File: Data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<lib:library xmlns:lib="http://java2s.com/ns/library">
  <lib:book id="b0836217462">
    <lib:title>Being a Dog Is a Full-Time Job</lib:title>
    <lib:authors>
      <person id="CMS">
        <name>Charles M Schulz</name>
      </person>
    </lib:authors>
  </lib:book>
</lib:library>
```

File: Schema.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://java2s.com/ns/library"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
  xmlns:lib="http://java2s.com/ns/library"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="another.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="library">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="book" type="lib:bookType" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="bookType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="authors">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="person" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

File: another.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="person" type="personType" />
  <xs:complexType name="personType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

It all seems to be OK, but when I try to generate Jaxb classes for these XSDs, I get following exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: undefined element declaration 'person'
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext$1.reportError(ParserContext.java:176)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.reportError(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:170)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef.resolve(DelayedRef.java:125)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef.run(DelayedRef.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.getResult(ParserContext.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.getResult(XSOMParser.java:226)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:519)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:236)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:411)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:603)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:142)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:300)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:380)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:257)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:477)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Adding `targetNamespace` to file `another.xsd` and qualifying it in file `Schema.xsd` solves the problem, but then element person in file `Delta.xml` will be in that targetNamespace, which is not what I want.

My question is basically: Why does JAXB (or XJC) not recognize the person element when it has no namespace?

For Jaxb generation I use cxf codegen plugin, which uses following: Version hudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2 of JAXB XJC

Comment: You need to be more specific on version numbers. Your schema is valid and it works fine with JAXB RI 2.2.147

Comment: Similar issue faced here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61372697/how-to-generate-java-classes-from-xsd-hierarchy-without-namespace Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have has nothing to do "import[ing an] xsd with no namespace". Your XSD, as listed, is perfectly fine. The problem is most likely with your setup, in that your XSD for the `person` object is not resolved/found and therefore loaded. To make sure that it is not your JAXB version (a very remote possibility), invoke the xjc/wsimport from a command line and take it from there...